# How do I print except for the &nbsp; from here to there?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I loaded a tag from this homepage.

like this code:

```
title = elements
      .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHtml)
      .toList();
```

How do I print except for the   from here to there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use where in List and use contains method for comparing "&nbsp".
Example

```
printElements(List elements) {
    List _tempElements = List();
    _tempElements = elements.where((element) => !element.toString().contains("&nbsp"));
    print(_tempElements);
  }
```